# section and subsection in headline

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage, headline

I am currently working on my bachelor thesis. I use the package `srclayer-scrpage` for headlines. As I don't need to print my thesis, it is a one-sided document. I want the current section or subsection name on the right side. I can use either `\automark{subsection}` or `\automark{section}` but in case of `\automark{subsection}`, a section with no subsections will be marked with the latest subsection and in case of `\automark{section}` no subsection will be marked. Have you any ideas to combine section and subsections in the headline?

Here is a small example of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\automark{subsection}

 \begin{document}
    \section{first section}
    This is a section with subsections, so using $\backslash$automark\{subsection\} will not cause any problems.
    \subsection{first subsection}first subsection
    \newpage \subsection{second subsection} second subsection
    \newpage \section{second section} This is a section with no subsections, so in the headline will appear \glqq second subsection\grqq \ instead of \glqq second section\grqq. How can I fix this? 
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use

```latex
\automark{section}
\automark*{subsection}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %11pt, a4paper,% default
  ngerman
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed for older TeX distributions
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle schrheadings automatically
\automark{section}
\automark*{subsection}
\clearpairofpagestyles% replaces outdated macro \clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% pagenumber should be on plain pages, too

 \begin{document}
    \section{first section}
    This is a section with subsections, so using $\backslash$automark\{subsection\} will not cause any problems.
    \subsection{first subsection}first subsection
    \newpage \subsection{second subsection} second subsection
    \newpage \section{second section} This is a section with no subsections, so in the headline will appear \glqq second subsection\grqq \ instead of \glqq second section\grqq. How can I fix this? 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, thanks!